# Media player that will properly loop a file with no intervening silence

Tags: windows, media-player

I've created a WAV file that loops perfectly, as verified by using Loop Play in the Audacity audio editor.  I want to keep the file small and have my media player loop it rather than having the file repeat its content over and over.  I used to use Media Player Classic for this, but I just tried with the latest version and it pauses slightly before looping (just like standard WMP, VLC, and other clients I've tried).  Are there any media players that will do this properly with no intervening gap?  Opening it in Audacity and manually starting a loop is more hassle than I'm interested in doing every time I want to listen.

Comment: Could you please list all the clients you have tried?

Comment: I have never noticed a significant delay in looping with VLC so it is probably a buffering problem - have you tried putting two copies of the file into a playlist and looping the playlist?

Comment: @SteveBarnes No improvement in VLC with a playlist.  WMP actually does a bit better with a playlist but there's still noticeable delay.

Comment: Sounds like you might be hitting hardware problems rather than SW - i.e. it is taking a perceptible time to read enough data from the hard disk to start playing - one thought *some* anti-virus programs can cause this when "On Access Scanning" is enabled...

Comment: @SteveBarnes I don't have that enabled and my reads for any other purpose are quite fast.  Using an SSD and so on.  The file is also 13 kB.

Comment: Sorry, was looking at the wrong one -- it's ~2.2 MB.  Less than your average MP3.

Comment: iTunes (too short to be an answer, but of all the software I tried it was the only one that flawlessly worked)

Comment: There are plans to [add gapless playback in VLC Player 4.0](https://www.neowin.net/news/vlc-40-to-drop-support-for-older-platforms-while-adding-new-ui-and-gapless-playback).

Comment: It's 2022 and this is STILL a problem... just tried SMPlayer, VLC media player, WMP, and Groove on Windows and NONE of them work properly (e.g. gapless looped playing, which seems like a basic feature i.e. worthless without it)

Answer (score 3):

[Foobar2000](http://www.foobar2000.org/) should support gapless playback - its supposed to work for lossless tracks, and WAV is, well not compressed, so is as lossless as they come. You'll likely need to create a playlist with a single track, and pick "Repeat(Track)" under Playback. You might also consider converting it to flac and playing around with metadata [as suggested here](http://wiki.hydrogenaud.io/index.php?title=Gapless#Testing_for_gapless), if that dosen't work

Answer (score 2):

[Mplayer](http://www.mplayerhq.hu/design7/info.html) is a media player for Linux and Windows that does gapless playback (no silence between tracks) including in loop mode. On the command line this is achieved with the `-loop 0` option (infinite loop).

> MPlayer is a movie player which runs on many systems (see the documentation). It plays most MPEG/VOB, AVI, Ogg/OGM, VIVO, ASF/WMA/WMV, QT/MOV/MP4, RealMedia, Matroska, NUT, NuppelVideo, FLI, YUV4MPEG, FILM, RoQ, PVA files, supported by many native, XAnim, and Win32 DLL codecs. You can watch VideoCD, SVCD, DVD, 3ivx, DivX 3/4/5, WMV and even H.264 movies.

If you want a graphical interface for Mplayer, check [SMplayer](http://smplayer.sourceforge.net/)

Comment: It's 2022 and SMPlayer under Windows does NOT work properly. Is there some setting required for it to properly invoke mplayer?

Comment: `mplayer.exe -loop 0` has a *significant* delay between instances of the loop.

Comment: `mplayer.exe <file> -loop 0` isn't quite seamless, there's a loud "click" or "pop" in between each loop.

Comment: [mpv](https://mpv.io/) is a modern fork of mplayer2 and supports gapless playback.

Answer (score 1):

I think you may have inadvertently answered your own question. You say an older version of Media Player Classic worked the way you like. Well, Media Player Classic is a [portable app](http://www.portablefreeware.com/index.php?id=42), meaning you can use it without installing anything. So get the version you used to use, and use that for that file.

If that doesn't work, then the problem is either something on your system that has changed, or you've misremembered what app you previously used.

Comment: If I knew the version I used years ago I would be posting here.  This isn't helpful.

Comment: @MatthewRead That's too bad. I wish that information was in your Question. At least my Answer got your Question bumped and is why you now have a few other programs to try. And, if those fail, I will point out that you can at least guess the early version based on approximately how long ago it was.

Comment: How can I loop on that classic player? There is no button.

Comment: @modiX From what I found in a Google search, it's in the menu (as Repeat File) in newer versions, and in the settings in older versions.

Answer (score 0):

Assuming that you need this to loop a small file and that you are not worried about good looking GUI why not:

1. Download and install [Python](http://www.python.org).
2. Download and install [PyAudio](https://pypi.python.org/pypi/PyAudio).
3. Write a simple script that:

   1. reads the whole file into RAM and Initialise the Audio port for output and
   2. in a blocking loop write the data you read above to the Audio Output

Or even - if you are on windows:

1. Download and install Python
2. Use a script like:

   `import winsound as w`

   `data = open.("YourWavFile.wav", "rb").read(-1)`

   `while(True):`

   ```
      w.PlaySound(data, w.SND_MEMORY | w.SND_NOSTOP)
   ```
3. Stop with `control-C`

You can even do this directly in the python console and if you need a GUI you could add one using a variety of libraries.

Comment: PlaySound() seems to expect a string for its first argument (`TypeError: must be str or None, not bytes`), so this doesn't work.  Using the filename for that string does not work either.  In any case, I am looking for a proper media player.

Comment: Sounds like there may be a problem with WinSound on Python 3 - *there is Issue 11620** should work with Python 2.7.x but if you need a GUI...

Comment: Although `winsound` appears to be a standard module, it isn't found on my cygwin system.

Answer (score 0):

There's a software called djv view,try that out.Loops like butter. 
It can even show exr files and that's a super plus.